# center a jdialog in a javafx stage

Tags: javafx, jdialog, stage

i am using a jdialog inside a javafx application and i want to show a jdialog center in the current javafx stage.. i tried following code  already but not working.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();//the owner
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                dialog.setContentPane(jasperViewer.getContentPane());
                dialog.setSize(500,650);

                Window window = dialog.getOwner();
                window.pack();
               window.setLocation((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width)/2 - window.getWidth()/2, (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height)/2 - window.getHeight()/2);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: The owner of a `JDialog` would be a awt window. Since as far as i understand it the "owner" would be a javafx window, you cannot use `getOwner`. You need to access the javafx window some other way...

Comment: @fabian i used getOwner on jdialog to get its window(of swing componenet)...yes i am facing the issue you mentioned..any work around?? thank you

Comment: There needs to be a reference to the javafx stage somewhere, which should provide properties similar to those of awt window... Use it. I've no idea how to access the stage though, since there's no info about that part in the question.

Comment: @fabian thanks for replying.. just say i have that reference to fx stage..how can i bind jdialog to that stage..since those are from different ui platforms..can you provide a example??

Comment: Binding? You probably this should be done by adding a listener to the relevant properties of the stage and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the `JDialog`... If you simply want to set the want to calculate the position based on the location of the stage at the time the `JDialog` is created the calcualtion for the location of the `JDialog` should be done like this: `x = stage.x + (stage.width - dialog.width)/2`

Comment: @fabian from binding i meant setting the jdialog on top of fxstage and also center of it?can you suggest a way to do it..my code shows the jdialog in the left corner of the  window..thank you